# Sudden influx of Korean spam

Tags: support, spam

Has someone been fiddling with the filters?

10 or so Korean spam posts on Super User within the past few minutes.

Can we get this banned?

Comment: Outright banning is a blunt tool. I've just tried to ask a question (https://superuser.com/questions/1188940/korean-in-notepad) in March 2017 and had the question stopped. I had to convert the text to an image. Why are we banning Korean anyway without a more sophisticated filter like "Can post in <BANNED-LANGUAGE-LIST> if reputation > 50" or similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was Korean spam, informally known as "bamwar". Google "bamwar spam" to find out more about this.

It often comes in waves. Today's wave was bad enough that an employee of Stack Exchange took action: Korean characters (in addition to Chinese) are currently blocked in post titles and bodies.

[image: like this]

Comment: I hope it is "slightly" more complicated rule.  I can imagine legitimate question/answer in english citing a short korean sentence.

Comment: Just had my legitimate question banned in March 2017 (https://superuser.com/questions/1188940/korean-in-notepad)! Can Stack Exchange sort this, please?