# Korean spam attack?

Tags: discussion, spam

We seem to be under an attack from a Korean spamming group. They make a post about every 3 minutes, which gets deleted through flag as spam in less than 1 minute.

Is there a way to stop this at all? Maybe something the mods can do?

Here's such post: https://superuser.com/questions/1488744 (one of the many)

Comment: The messages are in Korean, for what it's worth.

Comment: Ah indeed. They're Korean.

Comment: That link stopped working already, but metasmoke is collecting an archive of them as they arrive. Here is a similar one: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/201007

Comment: @tripleee weird, I can still see it if I click the link. It'll tell me the post has been deleted, but I can still see it through the revision history. Anyway, it seems the attack has stopped now.

Comment: If you have enough rep you can see deleted posts, but most of us can't

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. :D

Comment: "Ah indeed. They're Korean"  North or South?

Comment: Do they use different Korean characters @Moab? I just mistaken the language for chinese when it clearly was Korean.

Comment: It was an attempt at humor, like it would make a difference anyway, I assume it is South, North would be doing something more nefarious on this site.

Comment: Hahahaha @Moab you got me. :) good job. :D

Comment: [Sudden influx of Korean spam](https://meta.superuser.com/q/10730/241386)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll try to keep an eye out. The community team is aware and I know they have a very special spanner for throwing into the works here

Answer (score 15):

It's not just this site; MathOverflow, Stack Apps and Ask Ubuntu are under attack as well. [Here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?reason=9) is a list of those posts. [SmokeDetector will cast four spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/295232) on all these posts (so only two by 'real' users are necessary to destroy the spam), but unfortunately it has a bit of a backlog right now so it might take a while to kick in.

♦ moderators can't do much other than flagging as spam as well; the [Community Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/295232) can temporarily disable posting by unregistered accounts (though that doesn't help right now, as @Kulfy correctly notes) or try something else. Unfortunately, they have another far bigger problem at their hands at the moment, but I'll try to reach them about this.

Comment: The link is just to recent posts, maybe link to a slice from a specific time period?

Comment: I don't think disabling "anonymous" write access would be fruitful. Sites such as [ubuntu.se] require registration for posting.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The last spam wave I've seen was conducted by unregistered accounts, that's why I was suggesting that. But the Community Managers do have other tools at their disposal.

Comment: For those trying to reconstruct the event, it started with https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/200985 (currently on page 2 of the metasmoke search results for this particular reason) and ended with https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/201177 (still the first result for the search) for a total of 92 posts promoting 16 distinct domains in .net and .com with a link obfuscation using a comma and whitespace.